# How to fill page vertically?

Tags: xetex, plain-tex

I tried to print labels with UTF-8 input. I have read, that this requires `xetex`. So I wrote the following example to write `1€` in the four corners of a 102mm x 152mm label:

```
\pdfpagewidth=102mm
\pdfpageheight=152mm

\hsize=\pdfpagewidth
\vsize=\pdfpageheight

\advance\hoffset by -1in
\advance\voffset by -1in

\parindent=0pt
\nopagenumbers

\font\cmuss="CMU Sans Serif" at 12pt
\cmuss

1€\hfill 1€
\vfill
1€\hfill 1€

\bye
```

But the `\vfill` does not work.

> [image]

The second row is not at the bottom of the page but in the middle.

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just insert `\eject` before `\bye`. :-)

The explanation for what you saw is simply that `\bye` is defined this way in plain TeX (TeXbook p. 357):

```
\outer\def\bye{\par\vfill\supereject\end}
```

This is where the undesired `\vfill` comes from.

### Side note

There is a special rule used when TeX encounters `\end`. I'm giving it here for reference, because this was the first thing that came to mind, but it is **not involved here** (it triggers only when `\end` is encountered and either stuff from the main vertical list hasn't been processed by an `\output` routine, or there has been less `\shipout` calls than invocations of the `\output` routine—not the case here, because `\bye` and the default `\output` routine from plain TeX do the right thing). This rule is given in the TeXbook p. 264:

> When TeX sees an `\end` command, it terminates the job only if the
>   main vertical list has been entirely output and if `\deadcycles=0`.
>   Otherwise it inserts the equivalent of

```
\line{} \vfill \penalty-’10000000000
```

> into the main vertical list, and prepares to read the `\end` token
>   again. This has the effect of invoking the output routine repeatedly
>   until everything has been shipped out. In particular, the last column
>   of two-column format will not be lost.

Comment: So finishing with `\supereject\end` instead of `\bye` solves the problem, too.

Comment: Yes, it seems correct as well.

Answer (score 2):

Invoking the dangerous `filll` of "the highest infinity" (see p.72 of the TeXbook)

```
\pdfpagewidth=102mm
\pdfpageheight=152mm

\hsize=\pdfpagewidth
\vsize=\pdfpageheight

\advance\hoffset by -1in
\advance\voffset by -1in

\parindent=0pt
\nopagenumbers

%\font\cmuss="CMU Sans Serif" at 12pt
%\cmuss

1€\hfill 1€
\vskip 0pt plus 1filll

1€\hfill 1€

\bye
```

Comment: This adds much pressure on the rest of the page. It collapses every other `\vfill` on the page.

Comment: @ceving That is why it is so *dangerous* and that Knuth as a result did not provide the corresponding `\vfilll` macro in TeX.  Too hot to handle!  I thought it a curious oddity.